# Does saying "Hola Hola" imply impatience?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

On the radio this morning, where free legal advice was being given to callers, a caller was perhaps being viewed as overly polite by saying hi and good morning to the host and co-hosts, and the host said, "Hola Hola"

Was she stuttering, being emphatic, or is this doubling of "Hola" a way of saying, "Yeah, yeah, get on with it"?

Her tone of voice made me think that she was basically telling the caller, "enough with the niceties, let's go!"

Am I right?

Comment: I would say it's more emphatic or enthusiasm than impatience. It's like saying "How are you? Are you fine?". Of course, there would be situations when saying something like "Si hola, hola" mean "I don't have time for this stuff get to the point". The context is crucial. As an example, when I'm talking to my mother on the phone I usually say "Chau chau", like a single "chau" might sound cold, but again it's meaning is relative to the way you say it.

Comment: "Hola hola" is also very known as the introduction of one of the most successful radio programs on sports for many years in Spain. See http://www.kane3.es/radio/pepe-domingo-castano-y-paco-gonzalez-dos-hombres-y-un-destino-la-radio.php in the beginning.

Comment: Like Diego mentioned, `Hola Hola` its like "Hello Hello". For the Spanish speakers its kinda redundant and maybe awkward or silly when you hear it. A better option are > "Hola, buenos días" (hello, good morning) > "Hola, saludos a todos" (hello, good morning everybody).

Answer (score 7):

A mi me recuerda a Bugs Bunny de los "Looney Tones", que decía "Hola, hola amigos".

Realmente no simboliza impaciencia. Es una redundancia sin ningún significado, al menos en España. No estoy seguro en Latinoamérica.

Comment: In Latin America it doesn't imply impatience also. The same as you said,  the same thing in Latin America. It's only a friendly way to greet someone, but some cheesy girls abuse of this "Hola Hola" all the time. Some persons say this expression in order to catch the attention of some babies.

Answer (score 1):

You could be perceived as over polite by saying

> Hola. Buenos días

since it is a little bit redundant, but your listener but be also nitpicking to address you as such...

While "hola hola" is redundant, you can't rush someone with a "hi", so won't be perceived as a sign of impatience. As @Zukki points out, would be perceived as overenthusiastic.

If you have ever watched The Simpsons show, Krusty the Klown always greets the audience with an overenthusiastic "Hola hola!!" ("Hey, Hey, Kids!" in the original version). He is not being impatient nor rushing anyone, simply is calling for their attention.

Comment: Interesting that you mention the Simpsons, as the only Simpson I ever watched was O.J. (in his football years, not his court case) until now, where I am starting to watch the cartoon in Spanish (I never watched it in English).

Comment: Funny, in Mexico the combination "Hola, buenos días" is quite common and is a very comfortable greeting.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's used with question tune (¿Hola, hola?) to try to attract the attention of anyone who's distracted.

A single ¿Hola? is also used to this.